# Jquery function on doesn't work, no alert

Tags: jquery

All change on sections begining with section_langues_guides_ must launch alert :

```
$('section[id^="section_langues_guides_"]').on("change",function()
```

When I make a new section with clone function, and I change the section, I have no alert...

I displayed the generated code for the first section (this section works, alert displayed )

```
<section name="section_langues_guides_1" id="section_langues_guides_1">
    <input value="1" id="langue_guide_Français_1" type="checkbox"><label id="label_Français_1" for="langue_guide_Français_1">Français</label><input value="2" id="langue_guide_NL_1" type="checkbox"><label id="label_NL_1" for="langue_guide_NL_1">NL</label><input value="3" id="langue_guide_GB_1" type="checkbox"><label id="label_GB_1" for="langue_guide_GB_1">GB</label><input value="4" id="langue_guide_Esp_1" type="checkbox"><label id="label_Esp_1" for="langue_guide_Esp_1">Esp</label><input value="5" id="langue_guide_It_1" type="checkbox"><label id="label_It_1" for="langue_guide_It_1">It</label><input value="6" id="langue_guide_Allemand_1" type="checkbox"><label id="label_Allemand_1" for="langue_guide_Allemand_1">Allemand</label><input value="7" id="langue_guide_Suédois_1" type="checkbox"><label id="label_Suédois_1" for="langue_guide_Suédois_1">Suédois</label><input value="8" id="langue_guide_Arabe_1" type="checkbox"><label id="label_Arabe_1" for="langue_guide_Arabe_1">Arabe</label><input value="9" id="langue_guide_Japonais_1" type="checkbox"><label id="label_Japonais_1" for="langue_guide_Japonais_1">Japonais</label><input value="10" id="langue_guide_Portugais_1" type="checkbox"><label id="label_Portugais_1" for="langue_guide_Portugais_1">Portugais</label><input value="11" id="langue_guide_Hébreu_1" type="checkbox"><label id="label_Hébreu_1" for="langue_guide_Hébreu_1">Hébreu</label><input value="12" id="langue_guide_Russe_1" type="checkbox"><label id="label_Russe_1" for="langue_guide_Russe_1">Russe</label></section><br><br>
Guide(s) correspondant(s) :<br>
<select name="ld_guides_1" id="ld_guides_1"><option value="">-- Choisir un guide --</option></select><br><br>
<section name="section_infos_guide_1" id="section_infos_guide_1">
    Numéro national <input name="numero_national_guide_1" id="numero_national_guide_1" type="text"><br>
    Nom <input name="nom_1" id="nom_guide_1" type="text"><br>
    Prenom <input name="prenom_guide_1" id="prenom_guide_1" type="text"><br>
    Adresse <input size="40" name="rue_guide_1" id="rue_guide_1" type="text">
    n° <input size="5" name="numero_guide_1" id="numero_guide_1" type="text"> Boîte <input size="5" name="boite_guide_1" id="boite_guide_1" type="text"><br>
    Code postal <input name="cp_guide_1" id="cp_guide_1" type="text">
    Ville <input name="ville_guide_1" id="ville_guide_1" type="text"><br>
    MAIL <input name="mail_guide_1" id="mail_guide_1" type="text"><br>
    TEL <input name="telephone_guide_1" id="telephone_guide_1" type="text"><br>
    GSM <input name="gsm_guide_1" id="gsm_guide_1" type="text"><br>
    FAX <input name="fax_guide_1" id="fax_guide_1" type="text"><br>
</section><br>
```

and this is the code for the second section (alert not displayed)

```
<section name="section_langues_guides_2" id="section_langues_guides_2">
    <input value="1" id="langue_guide_Français_2" type="checkbox"><label id="label_Français_2" for="langue_guide_Français_2">Français</label><input value="2" id="langue_guide_NL_2" type="checkbox"><label id="label_NL_2" for="langue_guide_NL_2">NL</label><input value="3" id="langue_guide_GB_2" type="checkbox"><label id="label_GB_2" for="langue_guide_GB_2">GB</label><input value="4" id="langue_guide_Esp_2" type="checkbox"><label id="label_Esp_2" for="langue_guide_Esp_2">Esp</label><input value="5" id="langue_guide_It_2" type="checkbox"><label id="label_It_2" for="langue_guide_It_2">It</label><input value="6" id="langue_guide_Allemand_2" type="checkbox"><label id="label_Allemand_2" for="langue_guide_Allemand_2">Allemand</label><input value="7" id="langue_guide_Suédois_2" type="checkbox"><label id="label_Suédois_2" for="langue_guide_Suédois_2">Suédois</label><input value="8" id="langue_guide_Arabe_2" type="checkbox"><label id="label_Arabe_2" for="langue_guide_Arabe_2">Arabe</label><input value="9" id="langue_guide_Japonais_2" type="checkbox"><label id="label_Japonais_2" for="langue_guide_Japonais_2">Japonais</label><input value="10" id="langue_guide_Portugais_2" type="checkbox"><label id="label_Portugais_2" for="langue_guide_Portugais_2">Portugais</label><input value="11" id="langue_guide_Hébreu_2" type="checkbox"><label id="label_Hébreu_2" for="langue_guide_Hébreu_2">Hébreu</label><input value="12" id="langue_guide_Russe_2" type="checkbox"><label id="label_Russe_2" for="langue_guide_Russe_2">Russe</label></section><br><br>
Guide(s) correspondant(s) :<br>
<select name="ld_guides_2" id="ld_guides_2"><option value="">-- Choisir un guide --</option></select><br><br>
<section name="section_infos_guide_2" id="section_infos_guide_2">
    Numéro national <input name="numero_national_guide_2" id="numero_national_guide_2" type="text"><br>
    Nom <input name="nom_guide_2" id="nom_guide_2" type="text"><br>
    Prenom <input name="prenom_guide_2" id="prenom_guide_2" type="text"><br>
    Adresse <input size="40" name="rue_guide_2" id="rue_guide_2" type="text">
    n° <input size="5" name="numero_guide_2" id="numero_guide_2" type="text"> Boîte <input size="5" name="boite_guide_2" id="boite_guide_2" type="text"><br>
    Code postal <input name="cp_guide_2" id="cp_guide_2" type="text">
    Ville <input name="ville_guide_2" id="ville_guide_2" type="text"><br>
    MAIL <input name="mail_guide_2" id="mail_guide_2" type="text"><br>
    TEL <input name="telephone_guide_2" id="telephone_guide_2" type="text"><br>
    GSM <input name="gsm_guide_2" id="gsm_guide_2" type="text"><br>
    FAX <input name="fax_guide_2" id="fax_guide_2" type="text"><br>
</section><br>
```

Comment: javascript is not complete.

Comment: What do you mean by *"All change on"* ..? When exactly does a <section>'s fire change event!!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $('...').on is binding on your jQuery object you created before cloning, the cloned object is not bound to your alert function. According to the docs you could use:

```
$(document).on('change','section[id^="section_langues_guides_"] :input',function() {
    alert('!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### [Change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change)

> The change event is fired for `<input>`, `<select>`, and `<textarea>` elements when a change to the element's value is committed by the user. Unlike the input event, the change event is not necessarily fired for each change to an element's value.

`<select>` does not trigger change, hence your code is not working.